# Return statement shorthand syntax

Tags: php, return

I am new to php developing but so far have been able to do whatever I want. I recently came across a strange syntax of writing a return statement:

```
public static function return_taxonomy_field_value( $value )
{ 
   return (! empty(self::$settings['tax_value']) ) ? self::$settings['tax_value'] : $value;
}
```

I get the `return()` and the `!empty()` but after that it has a `?` and that's where I get lost. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks guys

Comment: You should mention in the Question title or in the tag (not just in the question text) that you are talking about PHP :)

Comment: It's called a "ternary" operator.  [http://php.net/ternary](http://php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary).  `return a ? b : c;` is shorthand for `if(a) { return b; } else{ return c; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a ternary operator, a short version of the `if` statement.

This:

```
$a = $test ? $b : $c;
```

is the same as:

```
if($test)
{
    $a=$b;
}
else
{
    $a=$c;
}
```

so basically your example is equivalent to:

```
if(! empty(self::$settings['tax_value'])
{
    return self::$settings['tax_value'];
}
else
{
    return $value;
}
```

You can find some more info [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/), together with some tips for precautions when using ternary operators.

### Important note about the difference from other languages

Since the question is marked as a duplicate of another question that deals with ternary operator in Objective-C, I feel this difference needs to be addressed.

The ternary operator in PHP has a different associativity than the one in C language (and all others as far as I know). To illustrate this, consider the following example:

```
$val = "B";
$choice = ( ($val == "A") ? 1 : ($val == "B") ? 2 : ($val == "C") ? 3 : 0 );
echo $choice;
```

The result of this code (in PHP) will be `3`, even though it would seem that `2` should be the correct answer. This is due to weird associativity implementation that threats the upper expression as:

```
( ( ( ($val=="A") ? 1 : ($val=="B") ) ? 2 : ) ($val=="C") ? 3 : 0 )  
  ▲ ▲                               ▲       ▲  
  | |                               |       |  
  \  \_____________________________/        /  
   \_______________________________________/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called the ternary operator - have a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

This basically translates to [statement] ? [true execution path] : [false execution path]

In your case, this would do the following:

```
if(! empty(self::$settings['tax_value']) ) 
    return self::$settings['tax_value'];
else 
    return $value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a shorthand if statement. Consider the following code

```
$Test = true ? 1 : 3;
//  test is 1
$Test = false ? 1 : 3;
//  test is 3
```